# SwaggerUI passing parameters

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a swagger.json defined like this:

```
"/API/GetTieredInventory": {
        "post": {
            "summary": "Get Tiered inventory from ID",
            "description": "Gets Tiered inventory for passed ID/IC combination",
            "produces": [
                "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "id",
                    "in": "path",
                    "description": "ID to retrieve Tiered inventory for",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ic",
                    "in": "path",
                    "description": "IC to retrieve Tiered inventory for",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "successful operation"
                },
                "500": {
                    "description": "Internal error"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Now, my API takes the parameters like this:

```
private function GetTieredInventory() {
    if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
        $this->response('Error code 405, Method not allowed.',405);
    }
    if(is_array($this->_request['ic'])) {
        $v = array();       
        foreach($this->_request['ic'] as $i) {
            $v[] = "'".$i."'";
        }
        $ic=html_entity_decode(implode(',', $v ));
    } else {
        $ic = "'".$this->_request['ic']."'";
    }
    $id=pg_escape_string($this->_request['id']);

    <SNIP DB CODE>

    try 
    {       
        $results = pg_query($sql);
        if(pg_num_rows($results) == 0) {
            $rows = [];
        }
        else
        {
            $data = pg_fetch_all($results);
            foreach($data as $item)
            {                    
                $rows[$item["ic"]][] = $item;
            }
        }
        pg_free_result($results);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $err = array("message"=>$e->getMessage(), "code"=> $e->getCode(), "error"=>$e->__toString().",\n".print_r($_REQUEST, true));
        $this->response($this->toJSON($err),500);
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

It doesn't matter what the `in` value is, I still get a
`Notice: Undefined index: ic` and
`Notice: Undefined index: id` error 
returned.

I have tried all three of these for both parameters:

```
"in": "path",
"in": "query",
"in": "body",
```

This is how the api is called in my service:

```
$fields = array(
    'id' => $this->compId,
    'ic'    => $ic
); 
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$url = "/API/GetTieredInventory";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**changed the parameters definition like this because `ic` can be an array of values:**

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "id",
        "in": "body",
        "description": "ID to retrieve Tiered inventory for",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "ic",
        "in": "body",
        "schema": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "style": "form"
            }
        },
        "description": "Interchange to retrieve Tiered inventory for",
        "required": true
    }
],
```

But still same errors...:-(

Comment: What URL do you use to call the endpoint? `in: path` parameters mean the endpoint needs to be defined as `/API/GetTieredInventory/{id}/{ic}` and called like `POST /API/GetTieredInventory/abc/def`. `in: query` means you need to call the endpoint as  `POST /API/GetTieredInventory?id=abc&ic=def`. See [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/) for the differences between various parameter types in OpenAPI/Swagger.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how cURL is calling the endpoint.I know the differences but I've tied using all 3 and got the same error.

Comment: In reviewing the Request headers, I see that the `querystring` only contains the `rquest` variable which determines which function is being called. The request method is POST and the Content-Type is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". However, if I set the `in` value to `body`, I still get the error. I can't have it as path because I may have an array of `ic` values.

Comment: no, it is not public, You don't need access to figure this one out

Comment: then how would you define the parameters for a form that had multiple fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the parameters to this made it work. I am using OAS 2.0

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "id",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "ID to retrieve Tiered inventory for",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "ic",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "IC to retrieve Tiered inventory for",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
    }
],
```